# x-inverted obj importer in BulletSharp - what's wrong?

Tags: c#, models, graphics-programming, bullet-physics, import

See [dead link removed] at the repository.

Screenshot:

[broken image removed]

Left: bullet imported version, right: correct 3ds max version.

It's somehow inverted. If you think that left part is just 180 degrees rotated you are wrong. Just rotate it yourself in Paint and you'll see - they will be different.

What's wrong with the bullet importer?

Usage:

```
        var wo = new WavefrontObj();

        int tcount = wo.LoadObj(path);

        Vector3 localScaling = new Vector3(1, 1, 1) * 1f;

        var vertices = wo.Vertices.Select(v => Vector3.Modulate(new Vector3(v.X, v.Y, v.Z), localScaling)).ToArray();
        var indices = wo.Indices;

        if (tcount > 0)
        {
            var trimesh = new TriangleMesh();
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < tcount; i++)
            {
                int index0 = indices[i * 3];
                int index1 = indices[i * 3 + 1];
                int index2 = indices[i * 3 + 2];

                Vector3 vertex0 = vertices[index0];
                Vector3 vertex1 = vertices[index1];
                Vector3 vertex2 = vertices[index2];

                trimesh.AddTriangle(vertex0, vertex1, vertex2);
            }
            CollisionShape concaveShape = new BvhTriangleMeshShape(trimesh, false);
            CreateRigidbody(transform.Position, transform.Rotation, concaveShape);
        }
```

I tried to import with Assimp and got the same result. So the importer is correct but something inside the bullet mirrors it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 3dsMax exported models with flipped YZ (Poser like) setting (checked by default) you should invert Z axis and swap vertices (like 0 1 2 to 2 1 0).

```
    var wo = new WavefrontObj();

    int tcount = wo.LoadObj(path);

    Vector3 localScaling = new Vector3(1, 1, 1) * 1f;

    var vertices = wo.Vertices.Select(v => Vector3.Modulate(new Vector3(v.X, v.Y, -v.Z), localScaling)).ToArray();
    var indices = wo.Indices;

    if (tcount > 0)
    {
        var trimesh = new TriangleMesh();
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < tcount; i++)
        {
            int index0 = indices[i * 3];
            int index1 = indices[i * 3 + 1];
            int index2 = indices[i * 3 + 2];

            Vector3 vertex0 = vertices[index0];
            Vector3 vertex1 = vertices[index1];
            Vector3 vertex2 = vertices[index2];

            trimesh.AddTriangle(vertex2, vertex1, vertex0);
        }
        CollisionShape concaveShape = new BvhTriangleMeshShape(trimesh, false);
        CreateRigidbody(transform.Position, transform.Rotation, concaveShape);
    }
```